# Flutter money text formatting with TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, formatting, flutter-dependencies

I have created one widget for entering any amount(currency). While entering the amount it should be formatted automatically e.g `10000 should be 10,000`. For formatting, the text as currency I am using a package called `flutter_money_formatter`. This packaged does it jobs perfectly but when I use it to formate the text for the TextFormField it does not produce the correct result as you can see in the attached image.
[image]

**The following code is for the text field widget.**

Here I am formatting the value inside the input change method using the controller(I guess it is not the best way). I think the problem lies there.

```
import 'package:bright_group_tuition/helpers/Utility.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../helpers/Validators.dart';

class RoundedMoneyTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function onInput;
  final value;
  final Function onTap;
  final readOnly;

  RoundedMoneyTextFormField(
      {@required this.label,
      this.onInput,
      this.value,
      this.onTap,
      this.readOnly = false});

  @override
  _RoundedMoenyTextFromFieldState createState() =>
      _RoundedMoenyTextFromFieldState();
}

class _RoundedMoenyTextFromFieldState extends State<RoundedMoneyTextFormField> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String storedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = widget.value;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    storedValue = widget.value.toString();

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: TextFormField(
        readOnly: widget.readOnly,
        controller: controller,
        onChanged: (String val) {
          widget.onInput(val);
          setState(() {
            controller.text = Utility.formatCurrency(val, withOutDecimal: true);
            controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
          });
        },
        onTap: widget.onTap,
        validator: (String val){
          if(val.isEmpty) {
            return 'This field is required';
          }

          if(!isNumeric(Utility.cleanCurrencyFormat(val))) {
            return 'Invalid number';
          }
          return null;
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
        maxLines: null,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
          labelText: this.widget.label,
          fillColor: Colors.white70,
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          isDense: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The following code is for formatting the text as currency.
This code works perfectly fine everywhere except with the text field which I have created.

```
static String formatCurrency(String amount,
      {bool withSymbol = false, bool withOutDecimal = false}) {
    FlutterMoneyFormatter fmf = FlutterMoneyFormatter(
      amount: double.tryParse(amount),
      settings: MoneyFormatterSettings(
        symbol: '₹',
        thousandSeparator: ',',
        decimalSeparator: '.',
        symbolAndNumberSeparator: ' ',
        fractionDigits: 2,
      ),
    );

    if (withSymbol) {
      return fmf.output.symbolOnLeft;
    }

    if (withOutDecimal) {
      return fmf.output.withoutFractionDigits;
    }

    return fmf.output.nonSymbol;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Since the [flutter_money_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_money_formatter) was updated a long time ago, you can consider using [currency_text_input_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/currency_text_input_formatter) which also supports null safety language feature.

Here is an example except from the package documentation:

```
import 'package:currency_text_input_formatter/currency_text_input_formatter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final CurrencyTextInputFormatter _formatter = CurrencyTextInputFormatter();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                inputFormatters: [CurrencyTextInputFormatter()],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _formatter.format('000'),
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[_formatter],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              TextField(
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  CurrencyTextInputFormatter(
                    // locale: 'ko',
                    decimalDigits: 0,
                    symbol: 'USD',
                  ),
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]